# With Google Visualization is there a way to swap the x and y axis?

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

I have formatted a php array of data that contains teachers for the columns, and tests for the rows. I am using this same array for a ColumnChart and a Table. The data is correctly setup for the ColumnChart, but when I use it on the Table, the data is coming out opposite what I want it to (the teachers need to be on the left, and the tests need to be on the top).

Is there an easy way to switch the x and y axis's with Google Visualization without having to format it on the PHP side?

Here is some dummy GV stuff.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(studentdata, 0.5);

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(container)); 
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(container2)); 

table.draw(data, options); 
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just switch the x and y data with javascript before you pass it to GV.

```
var x = studentdata.y,
    y = studentdata.x;

studentdata.x = y;
studentdata.y = x;
```

But you know... switch x and y for whatever your student data actually has for variables.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal version of this chart is called a BarChart in Google's world, so you could use:

`var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(container2));`